# Show an AlertDialog after ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I want to show an alert dialog after closing progress dialog, but it always opens the alert dialog first.

#### Progress dialog function

```
public void launchRingDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(About.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading Image ...", true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    ringProgressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.fail);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {@
        Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                // Let the progress ring for 10 seconds...
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
    ///calling a;ert dialog right after it
    showAlertDialog(this, "Feedback recieved", "Thank you for your FeedBack :):):)", true);
}
```

#### Alert dialog function

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon
    alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);
    final String s = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.feed)).getText().toString();

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (s.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(About.this, "Please enter your feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: This is just a dump of code. It would be beneficial if you'd nail down your problem into a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise this will probably get closed as off-topic

Comment: You can always check if `ProgressDialog` is showing or not by `isShowing` method.

Comment: Instead of Thread use AsyncTask and show your AlertDialog at `onPostExecute` method of AsyncTask

Comment: listen my both functions are working properly, but if i call aler dialog function after progress dialog its only show alert dialog, but if i removed it, then progress dialog working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
 ringProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            showAlertDialog(this, "Feedback recieved", "Thank you for your FeedBack :):):)", true);

        }
    });
```

and you can also use this or even both:

```
 ringProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showAlertDialog(this, "Feedback Canceled", "Please take time to give us feedback", true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don't use comments for chatting. There's the [chat] for that. (You need 20 rep to talk, though). That being said, I have flagged this post for a moderator cleanup ;)